# Generating SSH-Keys for Git on Windows 7

Tags: git, windows-7, ssh-keys

I'm experiencing a strange error while attempting to generate SSH keys via the Git Bash command line tool as downloaded from (http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list). I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise and have full administrative privileges. When I run the following command from the Git Bash command line:

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"
```

(using my email address in place of your_email@youremail.com) I get a Windows error dialog box that pops up with the title

> ssh-keygen.exe - Application Error
>   The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.

Any ideas what may be causing this error?

Things I have tried to fix the problem (without success):

- Installing an earlier version of Git for Windows (I've tried 1.7.7, 1.7.6, 1.7.4 and 1.7.3).
- Running Git in compatibility mode.
- Searched the net for others experiencing the same error in relation to Git on Windows.

What might be causing this problem?

UPDATE: Despite not actually determining what was causing this error, I got around it by simply using Putty to log into a friends Linux box and generating the SSH keys from there. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

[This developer discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/browse_thread/thread/a404f9f442351f08/a44043039ec6a055?lnk=gst&q=unable+to+start+correctly#a44043039ec6a055) might be relevant. Maybe you could try an earlier version, as even 1.7.6 was released after those changes were added. [Version 1.7.4](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=Git-1.7.4-preview20110204.exe&can=1&q=&sort=-uploaded) would be earlier.

If that version works, you should report a bug on [the msysGit mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit). And if you find no help here, asking there would be a good idea anyway.

Comment: Hi dancek, I tried installing 1.7.4 however the problem persisted. This is very strange as I've never had this problem with Git on any other Windows 7 systems. Thanks for your help though. I will post back here once I find a solution to this problem.